# Gson object deserialisation

Tags: serialization, gson

Can you tell me how can I use Gson to extract two distinct object defined in this string:
http://json.parser.online.fr/

I attempt to use

```
gson.fromJson(json, SeedAttribs.class);
```

and

```
gson.fromJson(json, SettingsAttribs.class);
```

but neither is working. I'm surprised why not.
I would also need a way to replace this json string when particular object eg. `SeedAttribs` changes. I need a way to rewrite it while `SettingsAttribs` will NOT change at all.

How can this be done?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: What is your SettingsAttribs class source?

Comment: it is basically just model class with few String fields and its get/set methods...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your original JSon string contains correct format. The best way is to serialize your object with GSON. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  SettingsAttribs st = new SettingsAttribs();
  st.setField1("value1");
  st.setField2("value2");
  // report constructed object
  System.out.println("st: " + st);

  // serialize to json
  String json = gson.toJson(st, SettingsAttribs.class);
  System.out.println("json: " + json);

  // deserialize form json
  SettingsAttribs restoredSettings = gson.fromJson(json, SettingsAttribs.class);
  System.out.println("restoredSettings: " + restoredSettings);
}
```

It compiles and runs. The output it produces:

```
st: SettingsAttribs [field1=value1, field2=value2]
json: {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}
restoredSettings: SettingsAttribs [field1=value1, field2=value2]
```

And SettingsAttribs class:

```
  public class SettingsAttribs
  {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public String getField1()
    {
      return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1)
    {
      this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2()
    {
      return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2)
    {
      this.field2 = field2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return "SettingsAttribs [field1=" + field1 + ", field2=" + field2 + "]";
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes, this is the exact as gson projects google site says.
But, please, refer to my post more carefully! I would need a way to serialize more eg. 2 objects (SettingsAttribs.class and SeedAttribs.class) and deserialize and then after changing one of them serialize the changed one back to json string while not ganging the other one at all!
When I read about gson it seemd to me that it should work just similar like with one object but, Im making a mistake somewhere probably

Comment: When u serialize changed object, are you sure you not overriding json string of the other object instance? show your code how are you doing that...

Comment: well Im not. If you would read  more carefully, please, you would know that is what Im questioning here.
if I have
    gson.fromJson(json, SettingsAttribs.class);
then I can extract attributes from json string which SettingsAttribs contains. But after changing this object I need a way to craete a json consisting of this new object and old fields which have not been exracted from the old json string
Can't make it clearer